# The app.config file operation overtime in configuration common.logging and log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

When i configuration the log4net,it show operation over time `in:http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd`

The detail code is:

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <appender name="InfoFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="D:"/>
            <appendToFile value="true"/>
            <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyyMMdd&quot;.txt&quot;"/>

                     .........................
```

And it tips that reference schema contains error?

Why would this happen?

If i try to move :

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd"
```

It tips the elements schema info can not be find!!!

How could i deal it?

Comment: you need to mention the file value="D://log.txt" ...

Comment: Your question is quite hard to read please try to clarify. You should also consider to give your question an other title.

Comment: I can include this schema and it doesn't show any warnings/errors. Can you add additional information? It's hard to tell what the problem is.